# During resize event im setting the geometry for a widget , but the issue is the widgets ends are flickering

Tags: qt

SO i want to resize the widget when the user has completed the resize event? can any one help me out with this problem

Comment: You should not change geometry during resize event. What are you trying to achieve? Set immutable size? There is `QWidget::setFixedSize` for this.

Comment: @Amartel: There's nothing wrong with resizing/repositioning child widgets in the parent's resizeEvent() handler. Layouts are to be preferred, but sometimes (albeit rarely) doing it in resizeEvent() is the easiest way to achieve a certain effect.

Comment: Venki S, please add some code to show what you're trying